# how to pass parameter from underscore.js page to backbone.js navigate for url changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to pass two parameter called "data-idVendor", "data-idService" which is in search.html file.I want to send those parameter value to my Backbone navigate for URL changes.How to pass those parameter vale to my backbone.history.navigate.Please help me to solve this problem.

/search.html

```
   <div class="col-md-4 tour_1 serviceDetails" data-idVendor="<%=value.idVendor%>" data-idService="<%=value.idService%>">
    </div> 
<!-- eg: data-idVendor = 1, data-idService = 1  -->
```

/search.js

```
   events: {
        "click .serviceDetails": "openServiceDetail"
    },
    openServiceDetail: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var currentElement = $(event.currentTarget);

        /*How to pass those two value to backbone.history.navigate */  
        /*In the place of '/1/1/xyz' I want to send the dynamic data ' data-idVendor/data-idService/xyz' */ 

        Backbone.history.navigate('/1/1/xyz', {
            "trigger": true,
            replace: false
        });
        Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Use "+"

```
openServiceDetail: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Get jQuery value from params
    var data-idVendor = $(event.target).attr("data-idVendor");
    var data-idService = $(event.target).attr("data-idService");



    Backbone.history.navigate(data-idVendor + "/" + data-idService +"/xyz" ,               
    {
        "trigger": true,
        replace: false
    });
```

Comment: A `-` is an invalid character for a identifier name. Use something like `dataIdVendor`. Avoid calling `$(event.target)` every line as it construct a new jQuery object each time, just reuse the same one.